# how to change the date format in zend framework

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I am fetching date from database, it is in US date format. So while displaying that date in html I need to change it into Indian date format. So how can I do this.
My html part where am fetching date is given below

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Sale End Date:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" disabled="" value="<?= $this->oProduct->sale_end_date ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell how to do this please?

Comment: Just in case we dont know what an Indian formated data looks like, would you enlighten us please

Comment: U can use : `'$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));`  for details : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: i want to change 'Y-m-d' format to 'd-m-Y' format. Am fetching value from db in 'Y-m-d' format

Comment: how can use this inside my html , the place where am fetching value?

Comment: You want to use date as input inside your HTML form in indian format..? if yes then first change type to date, and let me know so that i could answer properly down below

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy to use it inside HTML. You have to use PHP coding inside HTML. Have a look at this code.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Sale End Date:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" disabled="" value="<?= $this->oProduct->sale_end_date ?>">
        <input type="date' value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2017)); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added an input, which is suppose to save dates, as you would have liked. The  `date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2017));`code does all the trick and the `d-m-Y` can also be written in many ways. If you need any further help, [Go here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060458/understanding-date-function-parameters-in-php)

Comment: Hope, this helps. Let me know, if any problem