# Understanding Date function Parameters in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am making a custom calendar in PHP Zend-framework2, from a web tutorial, but cannot understand what does the function parameters mean? Here is the code

```
$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
```

`$month` and `$year` are passed to this function, but don't understand what other parameters mean.
Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: You should read first PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php .After this you will know what you ask.

Comment: thkx, i got a rough idea, but the code is little complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mktime — Get Unix timestamp for a date. it's six parameters stand for hour minute second month day and year respectively.

date — Format a local time/date.
It's first parameter accept format designator and 'w' will return a numeric representation of the day of the week which starts from 0 (0 for Sunday). It's second optional parameter is an integer Unix timestamp that defaults to the current local time if a timestamp is not given.

Please cheek PHP official documentation, you will get more detail.

Documentation:

[miketime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)  [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Try editing my question @kevin. I am banned from asking questions due to bad questioning.

Answer (score 1):

You Code is: `$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));`
I have given you **[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)** before.
If you echo this code then we get print of how many of week you have.

```
$hour = 1;
$min = 0;
$sec = 0;
$day = 21;
$month = 2;
$year = 2017;
$running_day = date('h/i/s/m/d/Y',mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$month,$day,$year));
echo $running_day;
```

Output of this code: **[PHPFiddle](http://phpio.net/s/30ix)**

Comment: tnkx alot for your help

Comment: Its my pleasure. : )